# Yii2 - How I can set behavior afterFind()

Tags: php, yii, yii2

**Model:**

```
....

public $yourWay;

....
public function afterFind(){

    parent::afterFind();

    // echo $this->yourWay (Nothing display)

    //something like:
        switch($this->yourWay){
           //Do something
           case "abc":  break;
           //Do something
           case "cde":  break;
        }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$model = new Model(); 

$model->yourWay = 'oneway';

$dt = $model::find()->one();
```

I tried use `$model->scenario = "abc"` and `echo $this->scenario`, but it not working.

I'm new Yii2 so hoping someone can help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model in `afterFind()` is not the `$model` you are calling `find()` on. It is new object populated only by database data. You have to use static variable to pass anything to `afterFind()`. Keep nature of static variables in mind and set it to null once you are done with search so it does not affect later searches.

**Model:**

```
...
public static $yourWay;
...
public function afterFind(){

    parent::afterFind();

    switch(self::$yourWay){
        case "abc":
            break;

        case "cde":
            break;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$model = new Model();

$model::$yourWay = 'oneway';

$dt = $model::find()->one();

$model::$yourWay = null;
```

Comment: +1 `"It is new object populated only by database data"` made my day. No idea, why Yii is going that way, which will destroy the normal `$object->attribute` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch seems wrong  you should

```
   switch($this->yourWay){

       case "abc":  
         //Do something
         ....
         break;

       case "cde":  
         //Do something
         .....
         break;
    }
```